# grepl full string match using object in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector called `all.ethnicity`. I want to grepl (or any function) "Asian" and only get true for the First element and not for the second element "South Asian". Note: I must use `ethnicity.type` object.

```
all.ethnicity <- c("Asian", "South Asian", "European")
ethnicity.type <- "Asian"
grepl(ethnicity.type,all.ethnicity)
```

result

```
  [1]  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Probably makes more sense to just do `all.ethnicity == ethnicity.type`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the start (`^`) and end (`$`) groups to your pattern, e.g.

```
all.ethnicity <- c("Asian", "South Asian", "European")
ethnicity.type <- "^Asian$"
grepl(ethnicity.type, all.ethnicity)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try with pasting `^` (i.e. start of the string)

```
grepl("^Asian", all.ethnicity)
```